# I renounced ownership but didn’t put trading as true

Tags: solidity, trading

I renounced ownership but didn’t put trading as true .. it is a multi owner contract but for some reason I cannot enable trading yet can call every other function .. how can I remove lp now ?

https://bscscan.com/token/0xead569ffa81f2d40659568b359492b7ce3f3518c

How can I get my money back out ? I was experimenting and f’d up !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's nothing you could do.

To modify `tradingOpen` you need to call

```
function tradingStatus(bool newStatus) public onlyOwner {
    tradingOpen = newStatus;
}
```

Something that only an owner could do. The ownership was transferred at transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/0xbeb1e576ddd0885f6b4eeea6bc12a427f80e0c12bfc5fa7ea7ed9cd7a0670f43.

Unfortunately once the contract's owner is transferred only the target could change it back.

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(isOwner(msg.sender), "!OWNER"); _;
}

function isOwner(address account) public view returns (bool) {
    return account == owner;
}

function transferOwnership(address payable adr) public onlyOwner {
    owner = adr;
    authorizations[adr] = true;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(adr);
}
```